# Create your own HTML Textfield with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I came across the following http://ckeditor.com/demo , and was wondering if anyone had a basic tutorial how to implement this (or perhaps what key search terms I should use)?

Is this just a heavily modified TextField, or have they somehow managed to create a completely new TextField from scratch?

I tried googling this many times, and I always get pages relating to customizing the built-in TextField with CSS etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start if you want to learn how richtext web editors work is to look into the `contenteditable` attribute and the `document.execCommand` method (the best editors use a lot more than this, but these are at the foundation). Over-simplified, an editor consists of a `contenteditable` block and ways to invoke `document.execCommand` on the text selection.

But, speaking as a person who has actually developed an editor of this kind, you might be better off using an existing one (CKEditor being a great one, in my opinion).

Edit: Note that `contenteditable` is a proprietary (Microsoft) property, but most (all?) browsers have implemented it now, and it will be in HTML5.

Edit 2: I want to try to clear up a few misconceptions.

- A `div` or `iframe` isn't in itself editable, it requires the `contenteditable` attribute. The use of an `iframe` is typically a workaround for the fact that older Gecko browsers only supported an alternative editable property (`designMode`) that could only be applied to a whole document.
- While some operations of advanced editors probably do employ `innerHtml`, this isn't the key to making an editor on the web.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a textbox. It is a `DIV` that has lots of `HTML` injected to it with javascript.

The basic idea is that JavaScript uses the `innerHtml` property of the div and writes HTML to it.

Comment: Thanks this is really interesting. I will spend some time looking into this. Although unimportant at this stage I'm curious how they generate the blinking cursor?

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript implementation that replaces a input. It basically hides the input and uses it for storing and passing the data via POST.

Answer (score 0):

The advanced textfields I have seen have all been `iframe` or `div`. The code behind them is quiet messy and not very accessible.

**Proceed with caution!**

Comment: @Thorn007, um. TinyMCE and CKEditor have a pretty strong development teams behind them.

Comment: @smotchkkiss, while true, I'd agree that there's a huge learning curve when approaching the codebase of these projects. A simple editor is relatively painless, but these editors have a ton of features, and beyond that work around a ton of browser limitations. The code for that is necessarily going to be pretty massive.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [WYSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM) instead of WYSIWYG.